# Node-red: How to configure TCP in by msg or dashboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, nodes, node-red

I am currently making a gateway that require TCP configure by dashboard. I want to configure the port listening on by a input msg, however tcp in node does not take an input. I would like to know that is there a way to pass a msg input to configure tcp in node or some other nodes can take a msg as input and do the same thing as tcp in?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not currently possible to change TCP-in configuration dynamically.

Comment: @zhan-xianyi any particular reason to remove the accepted flag? The situation has not changed